# Display a progress bar when a search submit button is clicked until search results are loaded

Tags: javascript, php, progress-bar

I look for a way to display a progress bar in the following scenario in PHP:

1. search button is clicked at search.php
2. display a progress bar (showing percentage) over the page (a small popup window at the centre, for example)
3. Just before the search results are displayed at result.php, stop and hide the progress bar

Currently, JQuery and Bootstrap are available, but others can be added. I like simplicity. Do you have a good idea? Cheers!

search.php

```
<form class="form_container validationForm" action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control validationInput" name="search" placeholder="Type a search keyword"><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Search</button>
</form>
```

result.php

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          // Below is the query function
          <?php include('_partials/query_functions.php'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please provide us with your solution

Comment: please show what u have tried.where are you facing problem. u are asking for full code

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I understand and, in fact, tried several things. But I wanted to ask an open question in order to leave the door open for good ideas and different implementations. I thought there would be a simple enough solution. At least, I tried what @Pycc34 described and not succeeded. :(

Comment: I am still struggling, so it would be great if somebody can take a challenge. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

add this in `result.php`

```
<div class="spinner-border" id="loader" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

add attribute `id` your submit button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" >Search</button>
```

And in your `javascipt` file

```
$("#loader").hide();
$("#submit").on('click', function(){
    $("#loader").show();
})
```

Comment: Thank you! But, this is spinner, which is different from a progress bar. Anyway, I tried, but the spinner appears only at result.php (not at search.php). i.e. when the result page is loaded. Further, it does not disappear...I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: replace spinner <div> by progressBar